# Android - Wh is my activity being destroyed?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have an application that uses JNI and the NDK to run native C++ in background of the UI. The native layer is initialized in `onCreate`, and finalized in `onDestroy`.

```
public class XXXXActivity extends Activity
{
    TermScreenView mTermScreenView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        try
        {
            this.setRequestedOrientation( ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE );

            setContentView( R.layout.activity_XXXX );
            mTermScreenView = (TermScreenView) findViewById( R.id.termScreenView );

            if( ! initializeNative() )
            {
                Toast.makeText( getBaseContext(), "Failed to initialize", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                throw new Exception( "Failed to initialize native layer" );
            }
        }
        catch( Exception exc )
        {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        finalizeNative();

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public native boolean initializeNative();

    public native boolean finalizeNative();

    // Etc
}
```

For some reason, after `initializeNative` ends successfully by returning `true` and without throwing any exception in the native code and `onCreate` ends successfully too, `onDestroyed` gets called several milliseconds after.
Nothing is supposed to be called once onCreate ends in my application, except `onDestroy` when the user quits it.

I don't know why `onDestroy` is called since `onCreate` succeeds.
What could be the reason ?

Thank you :)

EDIT :
Here is the code from initializeNative :

```
jboolean XXXXActivity_initializeNative( JNIEnv * pEnv, jobject pActivityObject )
{
    TRACE_I( g_pJniLog, "::XXXXActivity_initializeNative() - Begin." );

    if( NULL != g_pAppAdapt )
    {
        TRACE_I( g_pJniLog, "::XXXXActivity_initializeNative() - End, already called." );
        return false;
    }

    jclass pActivityClass = pEnv->FindClass( "XXXXActivity" );
    assert( NULL != pActivityClass );
    TRACE_I( g_pJniLog, "::XXXXActivity_initializeNative() - pActivityClass = %p.", pActivityClass );

    g_pActivityClass = (jclass) pEnv->NewGlobalRef( pActivityClass );
    assert( NULL != g_pActivityClass );

    g_pActivityObject = (jobject) pEnv->NewGlobalRef( pActivityObject );
    assert( NULL != g_pActivityObject );

    TRACE_I( g_pJniLog, "::XXXXActivity_initializeNative() - Creating XXXXActivityAdapter." );
    g_pAppAdapt = new XXXXActivityAdapter();

    TRACE_I( g_pJniLog, "::XXXXActivity_initializeNative() - Initializing XXXXActivityAdapter." );
    g_pAppAdapt->InitializeInstance();

    TRACE_I( g_pJniLog, "::XXXXActivity_initializeNative() - End, success." );
    return true;

}
```

I don't think it would be relevant to provide more since since it would get very big. I can tell you that the function doesn't throw a native exception and doesn't return false.

Comment: The first thing I'd test is to comment out the call to initializeNative() and see what happens.

Comment: show some code in `initializeNative` will help.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It seems that not calling initialize native it not causing the bug, so i'll investigate more.

Comment: I have made sure that anything that might be thrown in `initializeNative` is caught, i also checked for JNI exceptions using `if( pEnv->ExceptionCheck() ) { pEnv->ExceptionDescribe(); pEnv->ExceptionClear(); }` but `onDestroy` is still being called if i don't uncomment the call to initializeNative. There is one call from C++ to JAVA deeper in initializeNative, but i'm also checking for JNI exceptions at the location of this call. Maybe that i'm not checking JNI exceptions properly or at the right moment.

Comment: I'm getting a strange behaviour : after onCreate, onDestroyed is called, and then onCreate is called again, but then, no more onDestroy is called. I frst thought that two instances of my application were logging into the same log cat, which would have explained that, but all the thread and process IDs are the same ! I tried after forcing the application to close in order to make sure that it's not already running when starting to debug, but same result. I'm lost.

Comment: @Glaucus (and Hong Duan) After more investigation i found out that onCreate is called twice as i wrote above and that the Bundle is not null at the second call.
Why would my activity be restored like this ? Thanks.

Comment: I found the problem. See my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem : setting the screen orientation is destroying the activity and recreating it.

To fix the problem i can either not change the screen orientation or check whether the Bundle passed to onCreate is null.

Thanks for those who helped me.

Comment: You can also manifest that your activity handles orientation changes: [`android:configChanges=orientation`](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)